# Why sometimes a parent element gets 0px height?

Tags: html, css

I've started with HTML and CSS a couple weeks ago and this happened several times, and I don't know why.

Sometimes I apply a background to the parent element, include something on it, but the `height` of the parent stays `0` instead receiving `height` of the children. And sometimes it does (which I believe should be the correct behavior no?)

My glossarySelector gets `0` height. Therefore my background color is not displayed.

```
.glossarySelector {
  background: #EFEFEF; 
}

<div class="glossarySelector">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Why?

You can see the full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gTKNk/3/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: This SO answer provides several ways of solving this issue, each with their advantages and disadvantages: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1633170/388916

---

An element is completely flat (0px height) when it has no children or if the children are removed from the page flow using `position: absolute` or floating. Since the list elements all have `float: left` there are no more elements inside *glossarySelector* to expand it's height.

I see you've created a class called "clearFix". Just add a div with that class inside the *glossarySelector* div to fix the floating issue:

```
<div class="glossarySelector">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearFix"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gTKNk/12/

Comment: Best explanation among the answers. Thanks.

Comment: this could be better, by adding clearfix to the parent element, where it should be, and adding the clearfix method to it. its better HTML/CSS. this solution is like "hacking" an extra element to "fix" things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "clearfix" on glossarySelector.

```
.glossarySelector
{
     background: #000;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

See [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best) for alternative clearfix methods.

Answer (score 0):

"overflow:hidden" is a trick that fix this problem. Hope this helps.

```
.glossarySelector
    {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
```

example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gTKNk/18/).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1633170/948445) explain everything about clear fix.

Answer (score 0):

thats because there is a `float: left` on the list items `<li>`

you could do this:

```
.glossarySelector {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

or [add a clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)

Answer (score -2):

The default display mode of a div is "block", wich does not wrap around it's content in all cases. You should add `display: inline-block;`

In your code, the list will still overlap on the right side, because of the `left: 30px` of the ul element, but if you replace it by `margin-left:30px;` or `padding-left:30px;` it will work fine ;)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's not correct? @Van Coding I can't use display:inline-block. It doesn't work with IE7.

Comment: No idea, why it was downvoted.. I love the guys that downvote, but don't give a reason for it.. :(